# Least square fitting multiple values

Tags: functions, surfaces, curves, least-squares, data-analysis

This question shows how to least square fit a function to some data points:
[Creating a function incrementally](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2065218/creating-a-function-incrementally)

That question/answer show how to fit a function of the form
$y=f(x)$ using $(x,y)$ pairs of data points.

That can be generalized to surfaces and hyper-volumes by instead of having powers of $x$, having the permutations of all the powers of each of the arguments.  For example, the function $z=f(x,y)=Axy+Bx+Cy+D$ would have an $A^TA$ matrix and $A^Tz$ vector that consisted of the combinations of the powers of $x$ and $y$: $x^1y^1,x^1y^0,x^0y^1,x^0y^0$ otherwise written as $xy,x,y,1$.

The pattern continues for higher dimension functions such as $w=f(x,y,z)$ and higher.

That all makes well enough sense to me but now I'm wondering, what if I have a vector function such as $(z,w)=f(x,y)$?

Is there a way, given $(x,y)$ points to do a least square fit function to those points?

If there isn't, are there any other decent / common methods to fit a function of that form to points?

Comment: In many cases you can estimate each equation separably. However, for testing you need to remember that generally the error terms will be correlated, you can e.g. google "Seemingly unrelated regressions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{\nu}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^{\mu}$. We have a sequence of $m$ measurements 
$$
\left\{ 
\left( x_{1_{k}}, x_{2_{k}}, x_{3_{k}}, \dots, x_{\nu_{k}} \right), 
\left( y_{1_{k}}, y_{2_{k}}, y_{3_{k}}, \dots, y_{\mu_{k}} \right) \right\}_{k=1}^{m}
$$
which we choose to approximate with a fit of order $d$:
$$
f \left( x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, \dots, x_{\nu} \right) = 
c_{000\dots0} + c_{100\dots0}x_{1} + c_{010\dots0}x_{2} + c_{001\dots0}x_{3} + c_{000\dots1}x_{\nu} +
c_{200\dots0}x_{1}^{2} + c_{110\dots0}x_{1}x_{2} + c_{101\dots0}x_{1}x_{3} + c_{000\dots2}x_{\nu}^{2} + \dots + c_{000\dots d} x_{\nu}^d 
$$
The linear system is 
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} c &= F \\
\left[
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    1 & x_{1_{1}} & x_{2_{1}} & x_{3_{1}} & \dots &  x_{\nu_{1}}^{d} \\
    1 & x_{1_{2}} & x_{2_{2}} & x_{3_{2}} & \dots &  x_{\nu_{2}}^{d} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots\\
    1 & x_{1_{m}} & x_{2_{m}} & x_{3_{m}} & \dots &  x_{\nu_{m}}^{d}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{cccc}
     c_{000\dots0_{1}} & c_{000\dots0_{2}} & \dots & c_{000\dots0_{\mu}} \\
     c_{100\dots0_{1}} & c_{100\dots0_{2}} & \dots & c_{100\dots0_{\mu}} \\
     c_{010\dots0_{1}} & c_{010\dots0_{2}} & \dots & c_{010\dots0_{\mu}} \\
     c_{001\dots0_{1}} & c_{001\dots0_{2}} & \dots & c_{001\dots0_{\mu}}  \\
     \vdots & \vdots  && \vdots \\
     c_{000\dots1_{1}} & c_{000\dots1_{2}} & \dots & c_{000\dots1_{\mu}}  \\
     c_{200\dots0_{1}} & c_{200\dots0_{2}} & \dots & c_{200\dots0_{\mu}}  \\
     \vdots & \vdots  && \vdots \\
     c_{000\dots d_{1}} & c_{000\dots d_{2}} & \dots & c_{000\dots d_{\mu}} 
  \end{array}
\right]
&=
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
     %
     f \left( \bar{x}_{1} \right)_{1} &
     f \left( \bar{x}_{1} \right)_{2} &
     \dots &
     f \left( \bar{x}_{1} \right)_{\mu} \\
     %
     f \left( \bar{x}_{2} \right)_{1} &
     f \left( \bar{x}_{2} \right)_{2} &
     \dots &
     f \left( \bar{x}_{2} \right)_{\mu} \\
     %
     \vdots & \vdots && \vdots \\
     %
     f \left( \bar{x}_{\nu} \right)_{1} &
     f \left( \bar{x}_{\nu} \right)_{2} &
     \dots &
     f \left( \bar{x}_{\nu} \right)_{\mu} \\
     %
  \end{array}
\right] \\
\end{align}
%
$$

Notation: $\bar{x}_{2}$ represents all $x$ values in the second measurement; $f\left(\bar{x}_{2}\right)_{3}$ is the third component of the vector function $f$ evaluated at the second measurement location.
$$
  \mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}, 
  \quad c\in\mathbb{C}^{n \times \mu},
  \quad F\in\mathbb{C}^{m \times \mu}.
$$